# javascript liberary based on d3.js for rendering big data

Tags: d3.js, bigdata

I am looking for a library (open source) based on `d3.js` which can render charts within **less than a second** with **millions of data points** (big data) without **hanging** the browser .

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: See there is no library as such...millions of points in d3(which renders in SVG) means millions of DOM elements....so browser will be heavy.
If you make graph in canvas then rendering and refresh will make the browser go hang.

Comment: Thanks @Cyril . Is there any d3 lib which can at least render 50000 data points ?

Comment: Do you mean data points on map...if so this approach you can show a million points on map https://github.com/cyrilcherian/million-points-on-map

Comment: I am looking for something which will work for bar chart or line charts too .

Comment: So you saying 50000 bar charts?..heavy (50000 rectangles will make iit slow)  
linecharts with 50000 datapoints is possible because in line chart its a single path DOM element.

Comment: This is good example for large data point line chart: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245... on inspect you will see there is only a single path DOM elelemnt thus you will not get browser hangups.

Comment: Yeah !! that’s the issue i am facing , I want to visualize big data somehow but it is hanging my browser .

Comment: Or may be you can think of lazy loading of bar chart...imean showing subset of data i guess no body likes to see 50000 bar chart in one go it will not be a good idea for visualization.

Comment: Thanks for the help  @Cyril . Will try the links you suggested .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the closest thing to what you want:

http://mourner.github.io/simplify-js/

It takes a series of points and simplifies the generated line. Then you can use other tools like D3 brush or crossfilter to filter / zoom into sections of the line that you're interested in.

Here's a link to crossfilter: http://square.github.io/crossfilter/.

You might have more success just using that directly to summarize your data. With "big data" you're generally not trying to show *all* the data at the same time.